# Error 500 with FOSRestBundle and Behat

Tags: symfony, response, behat, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to test my API with Behat, but I get 500 on every response.

The API works fine outside of Behat.

Here is the part of my config.yml file for the bundle :

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { priorities: ['json','html'], fallback_format: json }
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        failed_validation: 422
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    disable_csrf_role : IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
```

For my controller, I chose to extend the FOSRestController, using the get/cget/... syntax.
Here is an example of action.

```
<?php

namespace RcpIndex\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;

use RcpIndex\Bundle\CoreBundle\Form\RcpType;

/**
 * @package RcpIndex\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller
 */
class RcpController extends FOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
    use PaginatorTrait;

    /**
     * Get rcp list
     *
     * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
     *
     * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
     *
     * @QueryParam(name="page", requirements="\d+", default="1", description="Current page index")
     * @QueryParam(name="per_page", requirements="\d+", default="50", description="Number of elements displayed per page")
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  section="Rcp",
     *   description="Get rcp list",
     *   output="RcpIndex\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Rcp",
     *   statusCodes={
     *     200="OK",
     *     400="Bad request"
     *   }
     * )
     */
    public function cgetAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
    {
        list($offset, $limit) = $this->getStartAndLimitFromParams($paramFetcher);
        $entities = $this->get('rcpindex.manager.rcp')->findAllInRange($offset, $limit);

        return $this->view($entities, 200);
    }
//...
```

Then, there is my Behat feature. I use Behat\MinkExtension and Sanpi\Behatch as context providers.

```
Feature: Rcplist
    Scenario: Get empty list
        Given I add "CONTENT_TYPE" header equal to "application/json"
        When I send a GET request on "/api/1.0/rcps"
        Then the response status code should be 200
```

And I get the following error : "Current response status code is 500, but 200 expected."

I tried to debug it but the code runs well and the $this->view() method throw no catchable exception (and after searching a little, the View::create() method is working well).

I guess the "cgetAction" return is good, but it might be in the way the Response is handled. 
My poor knowledge of Symfony's response handling does not allow me to debug this.

Any idea where to look (or even better, any solution ?)

Comment: check app/logs/ files to see if it Symfony error. And show Your context file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problems. To check what raises the error, in the `ExceptionController` of the FOS/RestBundle bundle `vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php`, in the catch section of the `showAction()` method, try to directly dump the exception, you'll get more details:

```
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
        die();
        $message = 'An Exception was thrown while handling: ';
        $message.= $this->getExceptionMessage($exception);
        $response = new Response($message, Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, $exception->getHeaders());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Symfony 4, because I forgot to set environment variables in `.env.test`